FDA - converting time series data to functional data
I'm struggling with converting my pandas data frame to functional data. I have 57,788x10 data set, it consist of energy measurements of 10 different inverters with 15 minutes resolution.
Based on the documentation, I understand that grid points should be float type, so I converted my time measurements to numeric values and tried to execute following lines of code:
However, I got this error: ValueError: Expect x to not have duplicates.
What am I doing wrong? I would like to keep current names of columns if that is possible.
INV12.index = pd.to_numeric(INV12.index)
grid_points = INV12_T.columns.astype(float)
data_matrix = INV12_T
fd = skfda.FDataGrid(
data_matrix=data_matrix,
grid_points=grid_points,
)

My data frame

Could you please post a [mre] and the full traceback and error message?

Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions.
